# How to Add Columns/Rows to a Grid of Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jaredasch1/6dhc240q/5/

I know I've asked this question before, but I wasn't able to get a working answer for that. I'm working on a game where it starts out a 4 by 4 grid, and when you click on one of the divs, it toggles the color of the divs above, below, and next two the one being clicked on. This part is working perfectly fine, and when they are all the other color, they switch back to the original color. However, what I'm trying to do now has presented more of a challenge. Once they are all the second color, I want to add another column and row and reset them back to the original color.

This is where I have run into some trouble. For some reason, the grid isn't recreated. This is where you guys come in. I need hep writing a function or edits to my original script to make this happen. I have this all on a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredasch1/6dhc240q/5/)

I'll also post all of the code here.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <div id="button" class="on hover"></div>
    <br>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    </body>
```

The CSS

```
    .block {
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        border-radius:10px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:#33CCFF;
    }
    #button {
        height:100px;
        width:410px;
        border-radius:10px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:#FF6666;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .on {
        background-color:#D633FF;
    }
```

The JavaScript/jQuery

```
    var main = function () {
        var checkAll = function () {
            var allDivs = $("div.block");
            var classedDivs = $("div.block.on");

            var allDivsHaveClass = (allDivs.length === classedDivs.length);

            if (allDivsHaveClass) {
                allDivs.removeClass("on");
            }
        };
        $("div").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });
        $("div").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
        });
        $(".block").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("on");
            $(this).prev().toggleClass("on");
            $(this).nextAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");
            $(this).next().toggleClass("on");
            $(this).prevAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");
            checkAll();
        });
        $("#button").click(function () {
            $(".block").removeClass("on");
        });
        $(document).keydown(function (key) {
            if (event.which === 32) {
                $(".block").removeClass("on");
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(main);
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple: simply add a new row with the `.append()` function within the logic in the `checkAll()` function when you determine that the user has "finished" the game, i.e.:

```
if (allDivsHaveClass) {
    allDivs.removeClass("on");
    $('body').append('<br /> <div class="block hover"></div> <div class="block hover"></div> <div class="block hover"></div> <div class="block hover"></div>');
}
```

However, since you are now going to deal with dynamically added elements, you will have to use the jQuery `.on()` method to bind mouseenter, mouseleave and click events to `div.block` on the go. You are currently using the `.mouseenter()`, `.mouseleave()` and `.click()` methods, which will be problematic for newly added elements because they are not present in the DOM initially when the page is loaded. In other words, you will need to use:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'div', function () {
    // Code here
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', 'div', function () {
    // Code here
});
$(document).on('click', '.block', function () {
    // Code here
});
```

I have tested your game, and my solution works: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/6dhc240q/6/

p/s: When developing games, it is always nice to include a "cheat" button (in this case, marking all `<div>` with the class `.on`) so that you don't have to go through the entire game itself to check if a certain new feature works or not ;)

---

Other comments on your code:

- You might want to look into changing the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` into CSS `:hover` events, since you are simply doing the fading and this can be easily done with transition and opacity
- Update the markup such that you are using `<br />` instead of `<br>`
- Actually, don't use `<br />` at all because it has no semantic meaning in your case. It is used for line breaks for text. Instead, you can float all the blocks to the left

If you'd like to see the slightly modified code, you can view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/6dhc240q/7/

Comment: it did add a row, but how would you add a column at the same time?

Comment: Also, the second link doesn't work, if I click on the edgeit adds one to the next row

Comment: @Jasch1 When adding columns, do you want to keep the same size for the blocks, or shrink them so they fit within the same original width of the parent? Not sure what do you mean by "click on the edge it adds one to the next row".

Comment: keep at same size. I can shrink them if I change my mind. I'm planning on making the reset button change size depending on the amount of columns

Comment: @Jasch1 You mean, something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/6dhc240q/14/